# A Taylor formula for a Vandermonde-like determinant

Tags: real-analysis, determinants, interpolation

Let $f_0,\ldots,f_N$ be smooth functions over an interval $I\subset{\mathbb R}$. Let $x_0,\ldots,x_N\in I$ be given, and form the Vandermonde-like determinant
$$\Delta_N=\det((f_i(x_j)))_{0\le i,j\le N}.$$
I should bet that there exists an $a\in I$ such that
$$\Delta_N=\frac1{0!1!\cdots N!}\,V_N(\vec x)W_N(\vec f)(a),$$
where $V_N$ is the Vandermonde determinant $\prod_{i<j}(x_j-x_i)$ and $W_N$ is the Wronskian $\det((f_i^{(j)}))_{0\le i,j\le N}$.

This must be a well-known Taylor-like formula. I should appreciate an accurate reference, or a sketch of proof.

**Edit**. After Christian R.'s answer, who shows by a counter-example that the above claim is wrong, let me suggest a weaker property, that
$$\left|\Delta_N\right|\le\frac1{0!1!\cdots N!}\,\left|V_N(\vec x)\right|\cdot\|W_N(\vec f)\|_{L^\infty(I)}.$$
After all, if $W_N(\vec f)\equiv0$, then the functions $f_j$ are linearly dependent and $\Delta_N$ vanishes too.

Comment: I think this is equation 2.32 of [On Multivariate Interpolation](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/e8d8/69d7845b6bd2bcc42c530e91bdba1fd7c3d1.pdf) --- upon taking the determinant of both sides.

Comment: @Carlo: Eq. 2.32 does not seem to me to answer the OP's question which is more about a kind of mean value theorem with appearance of this mysterious $a$.

Comment: @Denis: are you sure about $(N!)!$ ? This combinatorial factor does not look right to me. Usually with Wronskians the kind of things that show up are products of factorials like $1!2!\ldots N!$.

Comment: @Abdelmalek. I agree. This is actually the product which I found. I mistakenly wrote it as $(N!)!$. I fix it.

Comment: Just a thought: I would try to find an analogue of the Hermite-Genocchi formula for your LHS divided by the Vandermonde of the points and the combinatorial factor. Correctness of this factor can be checked by collapsing the points as in the paper by Olver that Carlo mentioned. If such a formula exists the integrand will not just be the Wronskian but maybe one can later show its range of values is contained in that of Wronskian. Extremely interesting question BTW.

Comment: @Abdelmalek: indeed, this equation is not what the OP wrote, but what does seem to hold is the collapse $\lim_{x_0,x_1,\ldots x_N\rightarrow a}\Delta_N/V_N=W_N(a)/(0!1!\cdots N!)$

Comment: It seems to me that a slightly different identity holds in 3D. Let $\gamma(t) = (f_{1}(t), f_{2}(t), f_{3}(t))$. For each $a\leq b$ there exists $c \in [a,b]$ such that $\det(\gamma'(a), \gamma'(b), \gamma(a)-\gamma(b))=\frac{(a-b)^{4}}{12}W(\gamma'(c))$, where $W(\gamma'(c))$ is the Wronskian of $\gamma'(c)$.

Answer (score 6):

This isn't working. Let's look at the simplest case, $N=1$ (but the example works in general). Then the identity you are hoping for becomes
$$
\det \begin{pmatrix} f(a) & g(a) \\ f(b) & g(b) \end{pmatrix} = (b-a)\det \begin{pmatrix} f(c) & g(c) \\ f'(c) & g'(c) \end{pmatrix} ,
$$
for some $a\le c\le b$. However, taking $f(a)=f(b)=0$ won't force the Wronskian to be zero anywhere: for example, $f=\sin\pi\frac{x-a}{b-a}$, $g=\cos\pi\frac{x-a}{b-a}$ will make $W$ equal to a non-zero constant.

Comment: indeed, it only holds in the limit $a,b\rightarrow c$.

Comment: @Christian: good catch. It might still be worth finding an integral formula for LHS divided by Vandermonde of points and combinatorial factor.